# "&" symbol converted to \u0026 automatically

Tags: javascript

I have defined a string like this:

```
var urlBehind = "&_user=a21b054b-e8ef-42e1-b4c4-d19da89e65e4&_apikey=xj8GXys46puq3u3LrHKdjq5WoBoUpqCbhWhRX6FeEGrFyELD7WvSRM%2Bx0gjwZHgIfrlTGalyDjL8GiT7r97o7w%3D%3D&";
```

But when I return it to my console the first char "&" is converted to \u0026 automatically, like this:

```
{
    "result": "\u0026_user=a21b054b-e8ef-42e1-b4c4-d19da89e65e4\u0026_apikey=xj8GXys46puq3u3LrHKdjq5WoBoUpqCbhWhRX6FeEGrFyELD7WvSRM%2Bx0gjwZHgIfrlTGalyDjL8GiT7r97o7w%3D%3D\u0026"
}
```

How does this happen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What browser? How are you logging it? How does a string become an object? We need more details.

Comment: \u0026 is the unicode representation for the ampersand & character.

How are you using urlBehind? It looks like you have received the the variable on the server side. What are you doing between the the declaration and the result?

Comment: `"\u0026"` and `"&"` represents the same string in JavaScript/JSON. The JS engine does the conversion for you.